# How to get Tags/Category List Using Blogger API

Tags: blogger

Anyone know how to get  tag/category list using blogger api. Currently there is nothing documented about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From searching the docs and the mailing list of the Blogger API group, there isn't an official way to do this. [Here's one fairly good response](http://groups.google.com/group/bloggerDev/browse_thread/thread/c0277bcf41b63d88/4536b68ead75dbb5?lnk=gst&q=get+tags#4536b68ead75dbb5), which basically comprises of reading all the blog entries and counting up all of the tags and so forth. I believe the code in this thread is Python, you can find other threads by searching the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/bloggerDev

Answer (score 0):

Blogger calls them labels, but they can be found in the exported XML, they look like;

```
<category scheme='http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#' term='Some label'/>
```